# Help with expanding to second order in perturbation theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian, perturbation-theory, two-level-system

In McIntyre's Quantum Mechanics: a Paradigms approach (pg 318), we solve for the energies of a perturbed 2 level system to get that
$$E_1= E^{(0)}_1+\lambda H'_{11}+\frac{\lambda^2|H'_{12}|^2}{(E^{(0)}_1+\lambda H'_{11}-E^{(0)}_2-\lambda H'_{22})}$$
and
$$E_2= E^{(0)}_2+\lambda H'_{22}-\frac{\lambda^2|H'_{12}|^2}{(E^{(0)}_1+\lambda H'_{11}-E^{(0)}_2-\lambda H'_{22})}$$
The author then states that we "expand the above to second order in the expansion parameter $\lambda$" to get
$$E_1= E^{(0)}_1+\lambda H'_{11}+\frac{\lambda^2|H'_{12}|^2}{(E^{(0)}_1-E^{(0)}_2)}$$
and
$$E_2= E^{(0)}_2+\lambda H'_{22}+\frac{\lambda^2|H'_{12}|^2}{(E^{(0)}_2-E^{(0)}_1)}$$
I have two issues. Firstly, I am not sure how we get from the first set of equations to the second set. It seems as if the author has simply decided to drop all terms in the denominators containing a factor of $\lambda$. Secondly, I am not sure why the author refers to this as "expansion to second order in $\lambda$". An expansion to second order would surely entail taking a power series of the energy and then dropping all high degree terms. But this isn't what the author has done? How has the author gone from the first set of equations to the second and what justifies us in calling this an expansion?
Any help on this would be most appreciated!

Comment: I believe the terms in the denominator containing $\lambda$, are considered 3. order since the numerator is already 2. order in $\lambda$ (maybe one could think about it in terms of a power series for $\frac {1}{x}$). Second order expansion means keeping terms of order $\lambda^{2}$ and lower.

Comment: @user330563 I dont know why that would be the case. A fraction with a quadratic in the numerator ($\lambda ^2$) and a linear term in the denominator ($\lambda$) will necessarily behave linearly in $\lambda$ for large $|\lambda|$. Why would we treat something that behaves linearly as a cubic??

Comment: Im sorry that I cant give a more formal argument, but note that in perturbation theory we look at the limit of small $\lambda$, which justifies only keeping terms up to low orders.

Comment: Think about this more. For any function which has a finite $\lambda \to 0$ limit, $\lambda^2 f(\lambda)$ and $\lambda^2 f(0)$ are equal to second order.